# In org-mode, how do I keep the original path to images when using #+INCLUDE:?

Tags: latex, org-mode

I can use:

> #+INCLUDE:

to include an org file in another org file, which allows me to assemble, say, a website from various org files. I'm exporting from the `C-c C-e` exporter in org-mode 7.5.

I could maintain a quite complex publication this way. This modular approach is quite common in, e.g. LaTeX and Texinfo publications.

However, links to images no longer work from the #+INCLUDEd org files. What seems to be happening is that the path to the images is taken as being from the org file that I am exporting from, rather than the actual org file that references the image.

The only ways I can see to resolve this are to:

- use a flat file structure; or
- make the image path from the referencing file (which I might not know in advance) rather than itself.

Neither of these is really sustainable.

How do I tell org to use the correct image path from its own relevant org file rather than the parent org file?

Comment: Did you try using absolute paths to the images in the original file rather than relative paths?  That should remain constant no matter where it ends up included.

Comment: Yes. When I export the org file on its own, the images are included.

Comment: I mean in the `#+INCLUDE:`'d file, use `/full/path/to/image.jpg` rather than `./relative/path/to/image.jpg`.  Like that you're telling it exactly where to look for the file.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Full paths do work, but I tend to move busy org folders around between Linux and Windows PCs, so I rarely if ever use full paths with org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know of the exporter, `INCLUDE` files are inserted into the document before export.  Therefore the content is part of the document before it starts following paths to reach any links to files (images).

After a bit of testing you likely will need to use absolute file paths.  Since you move between Windows and Linux your best bet would be to use a consistent scheme on both starting from your home directory.

Like that you can make the Org link:
`[[~/path/to/image.jpg]]`, which will work on both systems (assuming you have set %HOME% on Windows).

Option 1 is potentially an alternative (although I agree it wouldn't be ideal at all), whereas the second option would have obvious pitfalls if you INCLUDE the file in more than one future document.